# Android Studio: xmlns:map not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-studio

After doing a lot of research, and not finding anything... quick question, does anybody has an idea why Android Studio is not taking the Map tag?  The code below is a fragment of the maps sample in the SDK. Already added google play services lib and support, but nothing.

It's showing the error

```
Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment.
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
<fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:cameraZoom="10" />
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like this Eclipse bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53283

Comment: So it seems like the only solution is to do it on the java code instead of the xml file, correct? Thanks you!

Comment: Yes, AFAIK the only reliable way to get this to work is via the Java code. This is a bug that hopefully will get fixed someday...

Comment: The thing is that it works fine on Eclipse, I just add the references to google play services and it works, but Android Studio doesn't. Thanks again CommonsWare!

Comment: Android Studio 1.4 still has this issue. Xml error shown, but works normally. Just have to ignore this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once I've been moving the map fragment into FrameLayout (so I could add a button on top of the map).

I don't know what I've really done as I'm a noob in Android apps and XML, but it looks that I found the solution :-)

I tried to make the trick including the fragment from a separate file (using 'include' directive) and once I put the bare map fragment without any namespace definitions it proposed me 2 options:
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
I realized that maybe the 2nd one will work in the original file (although in original file Android Studio is not proposing it, but only the 1st one instead).

Conclusion:
Just change this line:
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
with this:
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

AS I MENTIONED - I'M A NOOB AND MAYBE MY SOLUTION GOT SOME SIDE EFFECTS SO PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF SO (although everything seemed to be working fine by so far...).

That's my working map layout with a button on the top and no errors:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             
  tools:context="com.maverickrider.myapp.inviteActivity.MapsActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purpura_E51B4A">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

    map:cameraTargetLat="51.513259"
    map:cameraTargetLng="-0.129147"
    map:cameraTilt="30"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startActivityButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:onClick="cokolwiek"
    android:text="Baton z dupy"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</FrameLayout >
```

Comment: this is just the "tools" namespace with the name "map". it is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I did Project/Clean and the error went away and it works fine now.  This assumes that the map namespace is properly defined above where it's being used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 0.5.8 and the XML viewer is underlining the attrs with map: - however the app is building fine. YMMMV.